# Hypothesis testing question trying to find the p value

Tags: statistics

for each of the data sets find the p value

This is what I have so far

ts = (735-854)-0/38 = -3.13

|ts| = 3.13

I am having a hard time getting the P-value. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now from the t-distribution table you'll have
$$0.01<\frac{1}{2}p-value<0.025$$
$$\Rightarrow0.02<p-value<0.05$$